# Coloring application using Cocos2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I trying to make an empty CCSprite then I want to hand drawing on it using touch controls.

But, I don't have an idea how make it and don't know it's possible.

So, PLS help me or give me some advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a [demo program for CCRenderTexture](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/12/how-to-use-ccrendertexture-motion-blur-screenshots-drawing-sketches/) which shows you how to draw sprites (or whatever you want) with touches:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use CCRenderTexture example from Cocos2d for drawing.. 
Check out this link http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/8474

Comment: Thank you, max9xs. It's really helpful.^^